# Limit join with pagination

Tags: sql, sql-server

These are my db tables:

Users

```
| id | nme  |
|----|------|
| 1  | Adam |
| 2  | Bob  |
| 3  | Jan  |
| 4  | Nico |
```

Products

```
| id | price |
|----|-------|
| 1  | 500   |
| 2  | 700   |
| 3  | 900   |
```

Orders

```
| id | user_id | product_id |
|----|---------|------------|
| 1  | 1       | 1          |
| 2  | 1       | 2          |
| 3  | 1       | 3          |
| 7  | 3       | 1          |
| 8  | 3       | 2          |
| 9  | 3       | 3          |
| 10 | 4       | 3          |
```

I want to get up to 2 users, and their products bought. I came with this:

```
SELECT 
    users.id AS 'user_id', products.id AS 'product_id'
FROM 
    users
INNER JOIN 
    orders ON orders.user_id = users.id
INNER JOIN 
    products ON products.id = orders.product_id
ORDER BY 
    orders.id
OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 2 ROWS ONLY
```

But this returns:

```
| user_id | product_id |
|---------|------------|
| 1       | 1          |
| 1       | 2          |
```

What I want to get is up to 2 users, not orders. I want to get this:

```
| user_id | product_id |
|---------|------------|
| 1       | 1          |
| 1       | 2          |
| 1       | 3          |
| 3       | 1          |
| 3       | 2          |
| 3       | 3          |
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Have derived table (subquery) where you FETCH 2 from users table. Then JOIN.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan its sql-server

Answer (score 0):

You may use `DENSE_RANK` function with your join query as the following:

```
SELECT user_id, product_id
FROM
(
  SELECT U.id AS 'user_id', 
       P.id AS 'product_id',
       DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY U.id) dr
  FROM users U INNER JOIN orders O
  ON O.user_id = U.id
  INNER JOIN products P
  ON P.id = O.product_id
) T
WHERE dr between 1 and 2
ORDER BY user_id, product_id
```

`WHERE dr between 1 and 2` allows you to perform pagination according to the order of user ids, i.e if you want to get users from 3 to 5, it will be `WHERE dr between 3 and 5`.

Check this [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/jN2lsgU_).

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need a JOIN among tables but only using `[Orders]` table along with a window function such as `DENSE_RANK()` as seems the most suitable to filter out to return the result set such as

```
;WITH cte AS
(
 SELECT *, 
        DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY [user_id]) AS rn
   FROM [Orders]
)
SELECT [user_id], [product_id]
  FROM cte
 WHERE rn <= 2 -- returns only two user after sorted by their ids
 ORDER BY 1, 2
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/d05Q_lsf)</kbd>